# Как обработать событие внутри <a> без перехода по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="https://vk.com">
   <div>Показать 333 без перехода по ссылке</div>
   <div>Перейти по ссылке</div>
</a>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при клике на первый div в консоли выводилось 333, но не осуществлялся переход по ссылке, а при клике на второй - осуществлялся переход?

Нужен ответ на jquery

Comment: А зачем Вам тогда вообще атрибут <a>?

Comment: @letUser дополнил вопрос, теперь думаю понятно

Comment: Менять на лету вопрос конечно интересно

Comment: @AzizUmarov виноват, так вышло

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('a').click(e=>{
  if(e.target.matches('a div:first-child')){
    console.log(e.target);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://vk.com">
   <div>Показать 333 без перехода по ссылке</div>
   <div>Перейти по ссылке</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Только щас понял, event.preventDefault() не подойдет?

Comment: Подойдет конечно

Comment: @Alexander Просто  $("a").click(()=>{console.log(333); return false;}); сокращяется до $("a").click(()=>console.log(333)||false);

Comment: @AzizUmarov Ну `e.target` тоже мониторить надо

Comment: @AzizUmarov  `$("a").click(()=>console.log(333)||false);` можно сократить до `$("a").click(()=>!!console.log(333));`

Comment: @DiD буду иметь в виду :)) + от меня

Answer (score 1):

Так думаю

```js
$("a").click(()=>{console.log(333); return false;});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://vk.com">
   <div>Показать 333<div>
</a>
```